# Replacing JS content in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace the `.bio__content h4` text with the `newLinks` content I created in my JS file.

I'm trying to use the `forEach` function to display the `newLinks` to the page but it's not working for me. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I want to replace the the `.bio__content h4` content with `newLinks`, so I used the `replace()` function.

Is this not right?

HTML

```
 <div class="bio__content">
     <h1 itemprop="name">Name</h1>
        <div>
           <h4><%- profile.designations %></h4>
         </div>
  <div>
```

JS

```
var designation = JSContext.profile.designations.split(", ");
// designation = ['CAP', 'AEA', 'AAA']

var newLinks = designation.map(function(x) {
return "<a class='modal'>" + x + "</a>" });
// newLinks = ["<a class='hey'>CAP</a>", "<a class='hey'>AEA</a>", "<a class='hey'>AAA</a>"]

newLinks.forEach(function (e) {
  $(".bio__content").text().replace(".bio__content h4", e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function is a string function which replaces the a certain value within a string with another value. The function you should use to add html to a document using javascript is [$.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/). Also, it would be easier if you joined all links into one html string withe the [join function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and added it to the document.

```js
var designation = //JSContext.profile.designations.split(", ");
            designation = ['CAP', 'AEA', 'AAA']
            
            var newLinks = designation.map(function(x) {
            return "<a class='modal'>" + x + "</a>" });
            // newLinks = ["<a class='hey'>CAP</a>", "<a class='hey'>AEA</a>", "<a class='hey'>AAA</a>"]
            
             var linksString = newLinks.join("\n");
            $(".bio__content h4").html(linksString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bio__content">
             <h1 itemprop="name">Name</h1>
                <div>
                   <h4><%- profile.designations %></h4>
                 </div>
          <div>
```